# rails form to pdf and save to amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, pdf, amazon-s3, attachment

I have a form for users to fill out about specific attributes first_name,last_name etc.
I need to generate a pdf from this form and also send an email with the pdf of the form as an attachment.

My approach was to save it to Amazon S3 and somehow attach it in the create method in my controller.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you done this? what personal attempts?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use something like the *prawn* gem https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn . This will allow you to generate a PDF file from within your application. Your question is somewhat vague though, but you should be able to generate the PDF fairly easily using *prawn*